# Chrome Extension: chrome.storage is undefined

Tags: kotlin, google-chrome-extension

I added the following code to my otherwise-working Google Chrome Extension…

```
var storage = chrome.storage ;
console.log("storage is " + storage) ;
var bookmarks = chrome.bookmarks ;
console.log("bookmarks is " + bookmarks) ;
```

Upon running, the console says

```
storage is undefined
bookmarks is [object Object]
```

In other words, *bookmarks* works OK but *storage* is missing in action.  My manifest has requested both…

```
{
   ...
   "permissions": [ "bookmarks", "tabs", "storage" ],
}
```

In case it matters, this extension is installed as an External Extension on Mac OS X.  To make sure it was updated correctly, I copied the code above from the files installed into ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions.  And, of course, I've relaunched Chrome.

Why might chrome.storage be undefined?

Comment: You need to use messaging. The localstorage variables you set in Chrome extensions are private to the extension. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: `chrome.storage` requires Chrome 20+, you should probably upgrade your browser?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 26.

I'm only a 35-pointer on Stack Overflow, so I may not quite understand how to use it, but I think that Chris' comment was actually an answer.  I mean, it did answer my question.  Thank you, Chris.

Comment: I've further learned that there are two "local storage" API in Chrome: (1) regular HTML5 localStorage, and (2) Chrome's proprietary chrome.storage with advanced capabilities.  I was making the mistake of trying to use (2) when (1) was sufficient for my task.  With localStorage, no configuration, permissions, or jumping messages through hoops are required.  It "just works", for example:  localStorage.myKey = "My Value" ; // Beautiful!

Answer (score 6):

Edit: the answer below was written in 2013. Now in 2021, as
Irfan wrote in comment:

> chrome.storage is available from content script too. Your extension's
> content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a
> background page. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Original answer:

LocalStorage is only available in background pages and popup. If you need to acces to some data you will need to pass a message from your current page to a background page. Here is the code :

In your current page:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({action:"getstorage"}, function(response){
   console.log("storage is " + response.myVar);  
});
```

In the background page:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action == "focusWindow"){
    sendResponse({myVar: localStorage.myStorage});
  }
});
```

You can find more examples in the chrome documentation on [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

Comment: chrome.storage is available from content script too.
Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Comment: Irfan is right, my answer was written in 2013. Things have changed since.

Answer (score 3):

There is "Reload (Ctrl+R)" link inside extension on "Extensions" tab, clicking on it fixes the problem (I spent few hours). Nor disabling/enabling extension neither restarting Chrome browser will fix the problem. I hope it will save someone's time ;)

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem! :) It seems that the Manifesto only gets reloaded when you re-pack the extension or do this...