# chrome.storage not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a google chrome app, and I tried to use the chrome.storage.sync.get, and it says, "cannot read property sync of undefined". Can someone please tell me what is going on? I have tried copying and pasting the exact line from the chrome developer website.

The code is literally:

```
$(".thing").click(function() {chrome.storage.sync.set(stuff)}
```

As far as I can tell, the mistake is just that I'm trying to use the chrome storage API in Google Chrome, not as an app.

Comment: Did you declare storage permissions in your [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#manifest)?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman yes

Comment: Do these answers help you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14657833/2033671

Comment: Not enough context. This question is lucky-guess contest. My guess is that you're accessing `chrome.storage` from a DOM-injected script, which isn't gonna work.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've the same problem, so how can I pass variables from options.js to script.js? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielRanéaBarbosa, use DOM messages: [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/19312198)

Comment: @wOxxOm -- you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow these steps while you are using `chrome.storage.sync`

1. Declare storage permissions in your manifest.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Storage",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons":{
"256":"img/icon.png"
    },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "options.html"
    }

  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/app/background.js"]
  }

}
```

2. Reload your App in `chrome://extensions` so that your manifest.json gets updated in your browser.
3. Follow the exact syntax of `chrome.storage.sync` with its callback function.

Sample.js

```
$(".thing").click(function() {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({"myKey": "testPrefs"},function(){
       alert("object stored");
})
    chrome.storage.sync.get("myKey",function(obj){
        alert(obj.myKey);
    })
});
```

This will work for you. I tested this code in my chrome app.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that I was trying to run this in google chrome (browser), not as a chrome app. Chrome doesn't know it should parse the code as an app, and ignores the line about `chrome.storage`. Something to watch out for, chrome developers!